# How to record customer preference from SFMC email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, dataextensions, content-builder

I need your valuable advice to confirm about one of my problem. We have a use case where have to send a SFMC email which have a URL about some event. We would like to give the preference to customer in email body e.g when they would like to receive the reminder email to notify them about the event before actual start time.

Want to provide these below options in email body:

1. One week before the date of event
2. One day before from the event
3. Same Day just 30 mins before the event.

I want, once user choose any one option so data get store into my SFMC DE and accordingly send the reminder email.

Is this possible through SFMC email only without redirecting customers to landing page or any other advice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All clicks on SFMC email links are recorded in the [**_Click**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_click.htm&type=5) data view.  You could add `alias` tags for each of your option links and then use a Query Activity to get a list of those that clicked on each one.  This could be used to build your reminder segments.

In the email:

```
<br><a href="https://example.com/event1?option=1" alias="event1-option1">Option 1</a>
<br><a href="https://example.com/event1?option=2" alias="event1-option2">Option 2</a>
<br><a href="https://example.com/event1?option=3" alias="event1-option3">Option 2</a>
```

Query Activity for `event1-option1`:

```
select distinct
c.subscriberkey
from _Click c
where c.isunique = 1
and c.linkname = 'event1-option1'
/* name: event1_option1_audience */
/* target: event1_option1_audience */
/* action: overwrite */
```

To build your three segments, you'd need to schedule the queries to run on those intervals or join to an Event data extension and do the date calculations in the where-clause.

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your solution. But as you suggested, I can create the three link with different alias. So want to confirm that when user will click on any link so how to stop them to redirect to the page mentioned in URL.

Comment: @AVashisth, I don't see how you'd record the subscriber's preference without them clicking on a link and that redirecting to a landing page/page on your website. An HTML email doesn't allow you to run script, so your only option for recording the preference would be a click through.

Comment: @Macca Thank you for your confirmation. Understood your point.